# SwiftUI 4 - iOS 16: weird animation in a rating stars view

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui

I'm using the following code snippet to show a simple stars rating view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var rating: Float = 1.0
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 4) {
            ForEach (0 ..< filledStarsCount, id: \.self) { index in
                Button {
                    rating = Float(index + 1)
                    
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                }
              
            }
            
            ForEach (0 ..< emptyStarsCount, id: \.self) { index in
                Button {
                    rating = Float(index + filledStarsCount + 1)
                    
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "star")
                }
               
            }
        }
        .font(.title)
    }

    var emptyStarsCount: Int {
        filledStarsCount == 5 ? 0 : abs(5 - filledStarsCount  )
    }
    
    var filledStarsCount: Int {
        let rounded = Int(rating)
        if rounded > 5 { 
            return 5
        }
        else {
            return rounded
        }
    }
}
```

but whenever I tap on an empty star the view redraws in a weird way in iOS 16, and re-draws (with a little flash) in iOS 15.5, here is a video screenshot for the problem:

[image]

The code can be copied-pasted to try it out in XCode as is.

Answer (score 2):

The weird animation is because you aren't supposed to use the `ForEach` View struct (it is not a for loop) with a dynamic range, e.g. `0 ..< filledStarsCount`, it has to be a static range, e.g. `0 ..< 5`. The reason is it can't track changes when using indices as IDs, because if say there are 5 items and the item at index 0 is removed, there still is an item with index 0. So just create the 5 star positions and decide if each should have a filled image or not, e.g.

```
ForEach (0 ..< 5) { index in
    Button {
       rating = Float(index + 1)
    } label: {
       Image(systemName: rating < index ? "star.fill" : "star" ) // needs tested 
    }
}
```